# How to support 'double' and 'triple' in Dialogflow digit-string entities?

Tags: dialogflow-es

In Australia it is totally normal for a voice-assistant user to speak digit strings with 'double' and 'triple'. (Same in the UK - Where they also sometimes use "treble")

So "8845" is said "double eight four five".
"6663" will often be said as "triple six three".

Dialogflow doesn't seem to support this for any of the system digit-string entities that aim to understand a user speaking a string of digits.

So, anyone know how to support "double" and "triple" in digit strings in Dialogflow?

Do I have to 'roll my own'?

Answer (score 1):

To handle these cases, you can create a dev mapping entity (let's call it "number-extra"):

```
reference value            synonyms
88                         double eight
666                        triple six
```

Since there are only 10 "double" or "triple" variants (one for each digit), you can just create a mapping for each one (11, 22, 33, etc).

You also need a composite entity (let's call it "number"):

```
@numbers-extra
@sys.number
```

Both entities should return strings, so there will be no inconsistencies in the composite entity and the reference values should be easy to handle on the backend.

You should also add training phrases that use these entities, e.g. "My address is triple six three Main Street" and annotate the entities accordingly. This gives your model more information about how these entities are used and will improve accuracy.

This suggestion can be generalized for other sys entities as well. Missing city? Create an entity for cities and combine it with @sys.geo-city in a composite entity. Missing given-name? Same procedure.

Comment: I don't think that will work. "double eight" does not mean "28", it means "88". "triple" is not a synonym for "three". You need more logic than what you have shown to make it work. Right? Dialogflow needs to handle this because it is COMMON outside the US...

Comment: Apologies, my example didn't map to your original question. I've now updated my answer. Since there are only 10 "double" or "triple" variants (one for each digit), you can just create a mapping for each one.

Comment: Interesting. Still not quite there yet though, as I need a "digit-string" solution for something like "468826661" = "4 6 double 8 2 triple 6 1".

Comment: You should just be able to add "double 8" as a synonym for 88, etc., and then in the intent, configure the relevant property as a list so it expects multiple values. You'll then receive an array of values to your webhook.

Comment: OK, returning an array is a solution. Not particularly elegant though... If you work for Dialogflow Dan, please feedback that this is quite a poor situation for support in many English-speaking countries.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will do! I both work for Dialogflow and am British, so I understand your frustration :)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'm not going to award the answer yet, as dealing with an array in the webhook is a crappy solution (and is not dealing with in properly in Dialogflow). Let me know when you've made progress internally to handle this, and the Answer is yours!

Comment: Dan - Are you aware if the underlying language modelling has changed since early June? "double 4" now _usually_ comes back as "44" (I think Dialogflow never even SEES the word "double"), but sometimes it, frustratingly comes back like "24" (double=2 !!!!) and I have NO CHANCE to correct it. It feels like Google are working on it under the bonnet, but it't not fully-cooked yet. Any clues?

Comment: That sounds like a bug! Can you file a bug report via the support request form? https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: Actually, my "double=>2" report above was wrong. It's not doing that. What it is doing is simply _ignoring_ the words "double" and "triple" about half the time when I say them, returning a transcript (in digit form) as though I had never said the double/triple words. Definitely not fully-cooked...

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSML and some logic to accomplish this.

Parse "468826661" to be four six double eight two triple six one and then just send it like that in a `<speak></speak>` tag.

[Here are the docs for that](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml).

Comment: Sorry, the question is about understanding speech input, not output. SSML isn't much help if we don't understand the user in the first place. I have altered the question description to be clearer.

Comment: My bad.  Huh.  This is a tricky one.  You could use the $any parameter to capture "double four two" and match an intent and in the webhook parse it with custom code.  One challenge you will have is if you have any intent that looks for a number parameter it may get called first if the input is "four double two" (will match the four in my tests).

Comment: Dan's answer here is workable, but a bit of a hack; which shouldn't be required... Since he works for Dialogflow, I've pressured him to get a 'proper' solution before I award the answer!